# Hadoop real time implementation

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, apache-pig, sqoop

I would like to know how Hadoop components are used in real time.

here are my questions:

**data Importing/export:**

1. I know the options available in Sqoop but like to know how Sqoop is used in real time implementations (in common)
   if I'm correct

   1.1 sqoop commands placed in shell script and being called from schedulers/event triggers. can I have real time code-example on this, specifically passing parameters to Sqoop dynamically (such as table name) in shell script.

   1.2 believe Ooozie workflow could also be used. any examples please

**Pig**

2. how pig commands are commonly called in real time? via java programs?
   any realtime code-examples would be a great help
   if I am correct Pig is commonly used for data quality checks/cleanups on staging data before loading them in to actual hdfs path or as hive tables.
   and we could see pig scripts in shell scripts (in real time projects)

please correct me or add if I missed any

**Hive**

where we will see Hive commands  in real time scenarios?
in shell scripts or in java api calls for reporting?

**HBase**
Hbase commands are commonly called as api calls in languages like Java.
am I correct?

sorry for too many questions.  I don't see any article/blog on how these components are used in real time scenarios.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't see articles on the use of those components for realtime scenarios, is because those components are not realtime oriented, but batch oriented.

**Scoop**: not used in realtime - it is batch oriented. 
I would use something like Flume to ingest data.

**Pig, Hive**: Again, not realtime ready. Both are batch oriented. The setup time of each query/script can take tens of seconds. 
You can replace both with something like Spark Streaming (it even supports Flume).

**HBase**: It is a NoSQL database on top of HDFS. Can be used for realtime. Quick on inserts. It can be used from spark.

If you want to use those systems to help realtime apps, think of something like a [Lambda architecture](http://lambda-architecture.net/), that has a batch layer (using hive, pig and what not) and a speed layer, using streaming/realtime technologies.

Regards.